# Aplication Closes but one of the functions dont remain

Tags: android

GOOD DAY!

i am doing a project with a battery saving feature and it disables wifi, screen brightness to lowest possible and on ringer mode vibrate. but every time i close (pressing back button) or press a button that leads to another activity the brightness turning up (user preference). any idea why and how i can make it remain to low?

these are my codes.

```
btnBattSave.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);

    mode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);

    WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = getWindow().getAttributes();
    layoutParams.screenBrightness = 0;
    getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);



    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            "Wifi Turned Off \r \n "
            + "Silent Mode On \r \n "
            + "Brightness Turned Low",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();

   }});
 }      
    public void send(View arg1)
    {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, InformationActivity.class);         
        startActivity(i);
    }
    public void exit(View view)
    {
          System.exit(0);
    }
```

i also indicated the intent and the exit.

THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it by following way

```
 private int brightness;
 private ContentResolver mCR;
 private Window window;
```

Initialize this in onCreate method

```
 mCR = getContentResolver();
 window = getWindow();
```

add this in onclickListner()

```
//add here your value in place of 10  
Settings.System.putInt(mCR, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 10);
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutpars = window.getAttributes();
layoutpars.screenBrightness = brightness / (float)255;
window.setAttributes(layoutpars);
```

Comment: it works like a charm thank you! by the way how did it worked and what is ContentResolver and Window is for?

Comment: window to set in your current screen and ContetResolver for setting value in settings and mark it as accepted if this helps you.